Class of functions whose composition with any moment-generating/characteristic function remain MGF/CF
Are there any known results on the class of functions $f$ for which   $f(M_X)$ remains an mgf/cf for any  MGF/CF $M_X$.
Elementary examples of such functions are
$$f_{c}(x)=c,$$
$$f_{n}(x)=x^n,$$
and nice examples are
$$f_{\lambda}(x)=x e^{ \lambda \left(x -1\right)}$$
$$f_{\alpha, \lambda}(x)=\alpha e^{-\lambda}+e^{ \lambda \left(x -1\right)}$$
appeared in this answer ($\alpha, \lambda,  c>0$, $n \in \mathbb N$).
Also, inspired from $f_{\lambda}$, we have the following function:
$$f_{Y}(x)=\mathbb E \left (x^Y \right)=M_Y(\log x) $$
for any non-negative integer-valued random variable $Y$ with finite mgf $M_Y$ over $\mathbb R _{\, \ge 0}$ (e.g., $Y$ with geometric distribution cannot be used here); $f_{\lambda}$ is obtained from $Y$ with Poisson distribution.
Indeed, the set of such functions is a convex set. Moreover, the set is closed under multiplication.
It seems that every member of this set is obtained from multiplication/convex-combination of a number of the above functions (there may be a set of basic functions that generate all the set).

1) Can we determine the whole set, 2) show some interesting properties of the set, or 3) provide some other nice members, basically different from the above instances?

Update:
An interesting result provided in @Snoop's answer that characterizes the class of all functions whose composition with any (multivariate) CF remain CF. I think the result is correct (while I am not an expert in complex analysis).
Using the results given earlier in the OP, we can see that any infinitely differentiable function $f: [1,\infty) \to [1,\infty)$ with the following three sufficient conditions:

The  Maclaurin series of $f$ converges for any $x$
The coefficients of the Maclaurin series are non-negative
The coefficients of the Maclaurin series sum to 1

is a function whose composition with any MGF remains an MGF. I think using the result developed for CFs and noting $M_X(t)=\varphi_X(-ti)$, we can prove the above conditions are also necessary.

The following attempts to address characteristic functions; all feedback appreciated.
A continuous function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ is the Fourier transform of a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\varphi$ is positive semidefinite, that is, the matrices $[\varphi(\xi_k-\xi_\ell)]_{1\leq k,\ell \leq m}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\xi_1,...,\xi_m\in  \mathbb{R}^n$ are s.t. $\sum_{1\leq k,\ell \leq m}\varphi(\xi_k-\xi_\ell)\lambda_k\overline{\lambda}_\ell\geq 0$ for all choices $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\in  \mathbb{C}$ (i.e. Hermitian positive semi-definite matrices). Let us consider all such $\varphi$. You may want to first charaterise the functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f\circ \varphi$ are Fourier transforms of a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any $\varphi$ as above. Therefore, the question can be cast as which functions $f$ preserve continuity if applied to $\varphi$ and preserve the Hermitian positive semi-definiteness of the matrices $[\varphi(\xi_k-\xi_\ell)]_{1\leq k,\ell \leq m}$, in the sense that $\sum_{1\leq k,\ell \leq m}f(\varphi(\xi_k-\xi_\ell))\lambda_k\overline{\lambda}_\ell\geq 0$ for all choices $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\in  \mathbb{C}$, and in particular $[f(\varphi(\xi_k-\xi_\ell))]_{1\leq k,\ell \leq m}$ is Hermitian. It turns out (e.g. Th. 3.1 here; further properties in Lemma 3.2) that all $f$ that preserve the Hermitian positive semi-definiteness of matrices are characterised by the representation $f(z)=\sum_{\alpha,\beta \in \{0,1,2,...\}}c_{\alpha,\beta}z^\alpha\overline{z}^\beta$ where $c_{\alpha,\beta}\geq 0$ and the series converges absolutely. So if
$$(f\circ \varphi)(\xi)=\sum_{\alpha,\beta \in \{0,1,2,...\}}c_{\alpha,\beta}\varphi(\xi)^\alpha\overline{\varphi}(\xi)^\beta$$
is also continuous for any $\varphi$ as above, it is the Fourier transform of a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $\varphi$ as above. If $\sum_{\alpha,\beta \in \{0,1,2,...\}}c_{\alpha,\beta}=1$ and $\varphi$ is the Fourier transform of a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f\circ \varphi$ is the Fourier transform of a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks for the input! A question on mgfs. Using the results given in the OP, we can see that any function 1) whose Maclaurin series converges for any $x\ge1$, 2) whose Maclaurin series's coefficients are non-negative and 3) sum to 1, is a member of the set. Does your result implies that any other member of the set is infinitely differentiable and satisfies the above three conditions?

Hello @Amir, you're welcome. My post here concerns characteristic functions, which have this nice well-known characterisation of being continuous positive semidefinite functions, being Fourier transforms of probability measures. As for this moment, I am not aware of a similar result for MGFs (there might be one; in which case the linked reference in my post could possibly be useful to obtain something similar as this post). As a side note, CFs are notoriously more tractable than MGFs, which might not exist (CFs always exist).
